# Linux:Renaming files in a folder to sequential numbers

Tags: linux, shell

I want to change file 1, file 2 ... file 100 to 001, 002, ... 100, but it changes to completely different numbers. For example file1 is changed to 051.
this is my code

```
string_leng=`(ls -l | grep ^- | wc -l) | wc -L`
echo $string_leng
find .  | grep 'file' | nl -nrz -w$string_leng -v1 | while read n f; do mv "$f" "$n"; done
```

Comment: Try running just `find .`. You'll see it won't return folders in the desired order, you'll need a way to sort them first

Comment: What are the exact filenames before and after? `file 1`, `file 2`, ... to `001`, `002`, ...?

Comment: file name is "file"001 ... "file"100

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are some missing details in your question, but here are multiple ideas that will help you:

- avoid `grep` on command output. There are better ways. For example to count the files in a directory: `find directory -maxdepth 1 -type f | wc -l`
- `find` doesn't sort the output, then you need to use sort: `find . | sort -n` (with  `-n` option for numeric sort)
- `find .  | grep 'file'` is supposed to give you the names of files? Better use `find -type f`